# UINavigation with white color and button side shadow?

Tags: ios, user-interface, swift3

I use the following code but that will not work as i want.

```
self.layer.masksToBounds = false
self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8
self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 2.0)
self.layer.shadowRadius = 2
```

Above code will make navigation like shown in below image.

[image]

And i want a navigation like below image

[image]

Comment: turn off translucent and back ground colour set wight

Answer (score 0):

My guess - your UIView's background color is `.clear`, so you see the shadow color.

set background color prop of UIView to white, likewise:

```
self.backgroundColor = .white
```